# Dynamic Pivot Table Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, pivot-table

I am getting the error message -
`Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near ','.` when I run the below query. I can't figure out why the syntax is incorrect. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @Vendor AS INT = 41

CREATE TABLE #PivotData
(
    [ID] INT,
[Row] VARCHAR(MAX),
[Columns] VARCHAR(MAX),
[AggData] INT
)

INSERT INTO #PivotData

SELECT  V.Vendor_Key
    ,O.Location_Desc 
    ,P.Item_Desc
    ,IIF.Sales_Qty
FROM    PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Item_Inventory_Fact IIF
    INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Item_Purchases_Fact IPF
    ON IIF.Calendar_Key = IPF.Calendar_Key
    AND IIF.Organization_Key = IPF.Organization_Key
    AND IIF.Product_Key = IPF.Product_Key
INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Organization O
    ON IIF.Organization_Key = O.Organization_Key
INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Product P
    ON IIF.Product_Key = P.Product_Key
INNER JOIN PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Vendor V
    ON IPF.Vendor_Key = V.Vendor_Key
WHERE V.Vendor_key = @Vendor

DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Cols = STUFF ((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(P.Columns)
                FROM #PivotData P
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                ,1,1,'')

 SET @Query = 'SELECT Row, ' + @Cols + ' FROM
            (
                SELECT  Row
                        ,Column
                        ,Aggregate
                FROM #PivotData
            )x
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(Aggregate)
                FOR Row IN (' + @Cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE(@Query)

DROP TABLE #PivotData
```

Comment: Nothing is jumping out as clear issue. Can you change the execute to a select and post the content of your dynamic query instead of executing it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message isn't very helpful, but if you look at the generated query, and the fifth line in it you'll see that the error happens because you try to select from columns using incorrect names.

You create the temp table with the column names `[Row], [Columns], [AggData]`

but when you select and pivot from it you use these column names `Row, Column, Aggregate`

That won't work very well. The solution would be to use the correct column names in the `@query`.

Comment: @Ionic It does; I tested it before I posted it :)

Comment: Well I haven't the whole table structur so I can't test it properly. I can create a structure as guessed but this is normally not efficiently :D

Answer (score 0):

semicolons between the statements are missing ?

for example, between `create table` and `insert into` ...

Comment: can't be that. Ending `SQL` statements with semicolons is recommended, but not a must currently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest declaring default empty values for you variables and then concatenating your rows in a bit different way.

```
DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    , @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @Cols += N',' + QUOTENAME(P.Columns)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT P.Columns
    FROM #PivotData  AS P
    ) AS P;

-- Generated list should like this:
-- ,[column1],[column2],[column3]...[columnN]
-- Only first comma has to be removed in PIVOT
SET @Query += N'SELECT P.Row ' + @Cols + '
                FROM (
                    SELECT Row, Column, Aggregate
                    FROM #PivotData
                    ) AS S
                    PIVOT (
                        SUM(Aggregate)
                        FOR Row IN (' + STUFF(@Cols, 1, 1, '') + ')
                    ) AS P';

--PRINT @Query;
EXECUTE @Query;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your just defining the column string wrong. I haven't tested it, just read it. But your column string is something like `,[1],[2]`.
The `,` at the start is just wrong. Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @Vendor AS INT = 41

CREATE TABLE #PivotData
(
    [ID] INT,
[Row] VARCHAR(MAX),
[Columns] VARCHAR(MAX),
[AggData] INT
)

INSERT INTO #PivotData

SELECT  V.Vendor_Key
    ,O.Location_Desc 
    ,P.Item_Desc
    ,IIF.Sales_Qty
FROM    PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Item_Inventory_Fact IIF
    INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Item_Purchases_Fact IPF
    ON IIF.Calendar_Key = IPF.Calendar_Key
    AND IIF.Organization_Key = IPF.Organization_Key
    AND IIF.Product_Key = IPF.Product_Key
INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Organization O
    ON IIF.Organization_Key = O.Organization_Key
INNER JOIN  PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Product P
    ON IIF.Product_Key = P.Product_Key
INNER JOIN PDI.PDI_Warehouse_952_01.dbo.Vendor V
    ON IPF.Vendor_Key = V.Vendor_Key
WHERE V.Vendor_key = @Vendor

DECLARE @Cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + N',['+P.Columns+N']',
                    N'['+P.Columns+']')
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Columns FROM #PivotData) P

 SET @Query = 'SELECT Row, ' + @Cols + ' FROM
            (
                SELECT  Row
                        ,Column
                        ,Aggregate
                FROM #PivotData
            )x
            PIVOT
            (
                SUM(Aggregate)
                FOR Row IN (' + @Cols + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE(@Query)

DROP TABLE #PivotData
```

Comment: This is the message I receive with this query.

(11396 row(s) affected)
Msg 1056, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Hi, try it again. You may have duplicates in the columns definition. I added a `DISTINCT`. Just run it again. You neet to replace the part around `SELECT @Cols`

Comment: Yeah now I'm getting the original syntax error again. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: You mean the part with the maximum allowed numbers? If you just run a SELECT DISTINCT Columns on your data, how many rows do you get back?

Comment: @MattJohnson Take a look at my answer. It tells you exactly what is wrong and what you need to change to make the original code working.